# How to use multiple DoH providers using okhttp DnsOverHttps package?

Tags: android, dns, okhttp

Let's say I want to try Cloudflare DoH first and then in case of a failure fall back to Google's DoH, How can I do that?

Using a single provider is pretty straightforward, though.

```
  val appCache = Cache(File("cacheDir", "okhttpcache"), 10 * 1024 * 1024)
  val bootstrapClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().cache(appCache).build()

  val dns = DnsOverHttps.Builder().client(bootstrapClient)
    .url("https://dns.google/dns-query".toHttpUrl())
    .bootstrapDnsHosts(InetAddress.getByName("8.8.4.4"), InetAddress.getByName("8.8.8.8"))
    .build()

  val client = bootstrapClient.newBuilder().dns(dns).build()
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement your own Dns that chains the calls.

See https://github.com/yschimke/okurl/blob/0abaa8510dd5466d5e9a08ebe33a009c491749bf/src/main/kotlin/com/baulsupp/okurl/network/DnsSelector.kt for an example that delegates to another Dns implementation.  You will need two delegates and call one and then conditionally the other one.